# Where is the wslapi.lib file?

Tags: winapi, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm creating a project that uses [`WslIsDistributionRegistered()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt826867.aspx.) from the Windows Subsystem for Linux library.

In my Windows SDK libraries, `wslapi.lib` is missing. I've tried redownloading the newest SDKs, but I can't find `wslapi.lib` anywhere.

Where can I get `wslapi.lib`?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows SDK, there is no `wslapi.lib` file to statically link that `wslapi.dll` file. You've to call the [`WslIsDistributionRegistered()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt826867(v=vs.85).aspx) function with `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()`.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef BOOL(__stdcall *pIsDistroRegistered)(PCWSTR distroName);

int wmain(int wargc, wchar_t* wargv[]) {
    HMODULE dll = LoadLibraryExW(L"wslapi.dll", NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32);
    pIsDistroRegistered IsDistroRegistered = (IsDistroRegistered)GetProcAddress(dll, "WslIsDistributionRegistered");
    BOOL result = IsDistroRegistered(wargv[1]);

    if (result) 
        printf("Distribution name '%ls' is registerd\n", wargv[1]);
    else
        printf("Distribution name '%ls' is not registerd\n", wargv[1]);
}
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt826867.aspx) points out, that there *is* an import library. While this answer provides an alternative, it doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: @IInspectable No there is no import library present in Windows SDK. Even Microsoft programmers use this method. See this file of WSL-DistroLauncher https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL-DistroLauncher/blob/master/DistroLauncher/WslApiLoader.cpp

Comment: I know that it isn't in the current Windows SDK. That still doesn't answer the question: Where is it? Is it part of some other SDK? A separate download? A documentation bug? An SDK deployment bug?

Comment: What's the source for this information? Have you submitted a defect report?

Comment: This procedure works for me and others. So I never think of that. Forgive me!